# When creating a report, SSRS does not see all Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

For performance reasons (from 4 mins down to 20 seconds) I Insert data into #MRE for 4 columns, then add the two columns for the second table. I then perform an update on #MRE. Due to the indexes we use on our tables this is the most performant method. (My first version simply joined these two tables together, but it ran over 4 min for a small test case)

I have tested it stand alone in T SQL (2008 R2). It works. When I connect my dataset in VS 2012 it does not see/display the two columns from second table. (OrderTotal and PaymMode)

Is there a way to enable VS 2012's SSRS to see these other two columns?

```
create table #MRE
( 
CreatedBy nvarchar(5),
SalesID nvarchar(20),
SourceID nvarchar(20),
--OrderTotal numeric(28,12),
--PaymMode nvarchar(10),
SalesStatus nvarchar (30)   
)

        ALTER TABLE #MRE 
    ADD OrderTotal numeric(28,12)
    ALTER TABLE #MRE
    ADD PaymMode nvarchar(10)

    UPDATE #MRE
SET #MRE.OrderTotal = pt.[AMOUNT],
    #MRE.PaymMode = pt.[PAYMMODE]

FROM #MRE 
    join JSCUSTPAYMTABLE pt
     on #MRE.SalesID = pt.SALESID

where #MRE.SalesID = pt.SALESID
    and pt.DATAAREAID='mkc'
```

Comment: What query supplies data to SSRS dataset?

Comment: I don't see where are you populating your table and neither where you are selecting data

Comment: SSRS uses the first dataset returned, so if you're using a function or procedure within your query to get the final dataset you may not get what you intend

Comment: Wrap this in a stored procedure and it should behave as you expect.  Then set the connection in SSRS to Stored Procedure mode.

Comment: @ Yuriy and Projectile, This is both part of my larger stored procedure usp_RPT_CS_MRE.

@ msmucker0527 I think this is my problem. It is definitely not something I understood before. I am reworking now to see if I can resolve this.

Comment: @ msmucker0527 Yes, that was the issue. Thanks for the help!